# Mutual information of linearly transformed normal variable

Tags: normal-distribution, mutual-information

Given that we have a variable $\boldsymbol{x}{\sim}\mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{0},\boldsymbol{I}); \boldsymbol{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{F}$ where $F$ is the input size and we apply an affine transformation through a matrix $\boldsymbol{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{O\times F}$ and bias $\boldsymbol{b}\in\mathbb{R}^{O}$ such that $\boldsymbol{y} = \boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x} + \boldsymbol{b}$, what can be said about the mutual information between individual random variables e.g. $I(x_1 ; y_1)$ or the whole transformation $I(\boldsymbol{x} ; \boldsymbol{y})$?

Any references would be helpful, thank you!

Comment: It looks like a perfectly predictable map between the spaces (no error term or “noise”). Is that correct?

Comment: That is my thought, although it might involve an approximation e.g. getting the joint through: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3941840/product-of-marginal-gaussian-and-conditional-gaussian, but I am not completely sure and that is why I am asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\mathbf{X} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{I})$ and $\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{A}\mathbf{X} + \mathbf{b}$, then $\mathbf{Y} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{b},\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^T)$. Think of $\mathbf{A}$ as the multi-dimensional version of $\sigma$, and so $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^T$ is the multi-dimensional version of $\sigma^2$.

We know that
\begin{align}
I(\mathbf{X};\mathbf{Y}) &= h(\mathbf{Y}) - h(\mathbf{Y}|\mathbf{X})
\end{align}
where $h$ is the [differential entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy). Since $\mathbf{Y}$ is a function of $\mathbf{X}$, [then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)#Further_properties) $h(\mathbf{Y}|\mathbf{X}) = 0$, and so
$$
I(\mathbf{X};\mathbf{Y}) = h(\mathbf{Y})
$$
Since $\mathbf{Y} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{b},\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^T)$, we can find a closed-form expression for $h(\mathbf{Y})$. To do this, we will use the [fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy#Properties_of_differential_entropy) that given an arbitrary $d$-dimensional random vector $\mathbf{W} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{\Sigma})$,
$$
h(\mathbf{W}) = \frac{1}{2}\log\left[(2\pi e)^d \text{det}(\mathbf{\Sigma})\right]
$$
We can relate $\mathbf{Y}$ to $\mathbf{W}$ by letting
$$
\mathbf{Z} = \mathbf{Y} - E[\mathbf{Y}] = \mathbf{Y} - \mathbf{b}
$$
such that $\mathbf{Z} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^T)$. [Note that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy#Properties_of_differential_entropy) $h(\mathbf{Y}) = h(\mathbf{Z})$. Therefore,
$$
h(\mathbf{Z}) = \frac{1}{2}\log\left[(2\pi e)^d \text{det}\left(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^T\right)\right] = h(\mathbf{Y})
$$
This argument applies if $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ are real-valued.

Comment: Thank you, what if we do not know anything about $\boldsymbol{A}$ of $\boldsymbol{b}$ except that they are real? Also, I assume that by $f$ you mean identity?

Comment: @MartinFerianc I've edited my answer and addressed your comment.

Comment: Thank you for a clear explanation!

Comment: May I additionally please ask for a good reference e.g. a book on this such that I can study further? In particular, I am interested in a case where we introduce some nonlinearity on Y and hence then the mutual information will need to be estimated/approximated.

Comment: The book that was used in the Information Theory course that I took is [Elements of Information Theory](https://www.amazon.com/Elements-Information-Theory-Telecommunications-Processing/dp/0471241954) by Cover et al. This book is not the best. It is more like a reference manual, since it does not motivate most of the concepts. Nevertheless, it is well organized. You can find other good books on [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=information+theory).

Comment: I can see from your profile that you are interested in machine learning. In that case, I highly recommend a course on Information Theory. Although it seems more applicable to communications theory, it is actually very applicable to machine learning, such as [the Information Bottleneck method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_bottleneck_method) and [Deep Variational Information Bottleneck](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.00410).

Comment: Thank you very much for both suggestions!